# (In nextjs v13.4) Cookies being get in localhost but not to the deployed server on railway.app

Tags: node.js, express, next.js, cookies, next.js13

I am use my server using express js and my font-end using nextjs v13.4

when server localhost cookie works fine but when in deploy railway.app its not working in font-end like nextjs middleware.js(req.cookies.has("token")) get me undefiend/false (Note that browser cookie token visible its ok)

here my express js app.js cors implement code

```
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: [
      "https://e-golap-admin.vercel.app",
      "https://e-golap.vercel.app",
      "http://localhost:3000",
      "http://localhost:3001",
    ],
    methods: "GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE",
    credentials: true,
  })
);
// app.set("trust proxy", 1);
// app.enable("trust proxy");
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.header("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
  res.header(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
  );
  next();
});
```

And here my express js when user login then set cookies code

```
 Response.cookie("token", token, {
          domain: "e-golap.vercel.app/",
          // maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30, // 1 month
          maxAge: 2592000, // 1 month
          httpOnly: false,
          sameSite: "none",
          path: "/",
          secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production",
        });
```

And here my font-end (nextjs v13.4) middleware.js code

```
export async function middleware(req, res) {
  // check login
  let token = req.cookies.has("token");
  if (req.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/login")) {
    if (!token) {
      return NextResponse.next();
    } else {
      return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/", req.url));
    }
  }
  // check checkout && confirm order
  if (
    req.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/checkout") ||
    req.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/confirm-order") ||
    req.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/user-dashboard") ||
    req.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/user-dashboard/edit-profile") ||
    req.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/user-dashboard/orders/running-orders") ||
    req.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/user-dashboard/orders/delivery-orders") ||
    req.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/user-dashboard/orders/return-orders") ||
    req.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/user-dashboard/orders/cancel-orders")
  ) {
    let token = req.cookies.has("token");
    if (token) {
      return NextResponse.next();
    } else {
      return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/login", req.url));
    }
  }
}
```

Here

```
let token = req.cookies.has("token")
```

get me false but when server on localhost its work perfectly.

I want to when server deploy production. get me

```
let token = req.cookies.has("token")
```

get result true